# Count the number of topological sorts for poset (A|)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

can someone please explain to me how to count the number of topological sorts  for poset(A|) where A = {2,3,4,8,9,16,27,81} ? Quick example would be nice. Please help...I have an exam in several hours. Thanks !

Comment: What is the ordering on A? proper divisor?

Comment: Exact duplicate of part (c) in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569986/topological-orderings-of-a-poseta

Comment: yes the ordering is divisibilty

Answer (score 3):

There are two total orderings hidden in this poset:

$$2 | 4 | 8 | 16$$
$$3 | 9 | 27 | 81$$

The question is how many ways we can interleave them. The answer is just ${8 \choose 4} = 70$, i.e. we have to decide which four elements come from the first group and which from the second.