# Count the number of topological sorts for each poset

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Count the number of topological sorts for each partially ordered set $(A,|)$, where
(a) $A = (3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 16, 17)$ 
(b) $A = (1, 3, 9, 27, 81, 243)$

That is, you have to ﬁnd the number of ways to order the elements of the set A so that the
partial order imposed by divisibility is preserved.

Edit: I got the answer 7 choose 1 which is 7 for a) and 6 choose 6 which is 1 for b), is that correct?

Comment: What is a topological sort? For example consider this minimal example: $A=(p_1,p_2)$ with $p_1$ and $p_2$ coprime. In this case do you have two different sorts?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but I think I figured it out.

Comment: In general if  you permute two terms such that $a_1 \mid a_2$ this means that you must have $a_2 \mid a_1$ and in particular  if you are in a unique factorization domain  $a_1=a_2$.

Comment: In the minimal case you can sort $p_1$ and $p_2$ because their are not comparable. So changing switching them the divisibility order is preserved.

Comment: Probably I misunderstood your edit. In $(a)$, because the elements are pairwise co-prime the number of chooses that you can perform is equal to the number of permutation of a set of $7$ elements that is $7!$ (and not $7$). In $(b)$, because the elements are pairwise comparable the $\mid$ divisibility induces a total order, and so you have only $1$ choose. Ok?

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573395/count-the-number-of-topological-sorts-for-poset-a?lq=1)